# How to get AWStats to generate static HTML files?

Tags: configuration, debian, awstats

I want to get AWStats running on my webserver that runs Debian 4.4.5-8 with Apache 2.

There are several websites that all have their own configuration file, similar to this:

```
Include "/etc/awstats/awstats.model.conf"
LogFile="/var/customers/logs/myname-example.com-access.log"
LogType=W
LogFormat = 1
LogSeparator=" "
SiteDomain="example.com"
HostAliases="*.example.com"
DirData="/www/myname/awstats/example.com/"
```

What I expect is that HTML files are written to /www/myname/awstats/example.com/ which I can then access through Apache. However when I run [/usr/share/awstats/tools/buildstatic.sh](http://www.nsds.com/software/dist/awstats/debian-buildstatic.sh.txt) what happens is that .txt files are written to that directory and HTML files that I want are written to /var/cache/awstats. The error file in /tmp remains empty.

Why is this happening and how do I make it work the way I want?

Comment: This question is not really programming related. A better place to ask would be http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

DirData is not supposed to be read directly by the Web Server. It is used by awstats.pl.

The fact is that /var/cache/awstats is hardcoded in buildstatic.sh so you have to change the two lines mentioning it:

```
mkdir -p /var/cache/awstats/$c/$Y/$m/
```

and

```
-dir=/var/cache/awstats/$c/$Y/$m/ >$TMPFILE 2>&1
```